# Facebook Developers Add Platform

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an Android App where I needed to use the SDK provided by FB to enable login via FB.
Everything is OK and it works, but when I went at:

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/MY_APP_ID/settings/basic/

[image]

I saw that there is a button that says "**Add Platform**".

My question is, why should I add a platform for my APP if I have everything done without that?

Does anyone know when I might need to use that option, in which cases?
Any information would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Platforms are the different environments a Facebook app can run in/under - website, canvas, page tab, iOS, android, etc. If your app is an Android app - then add the Android platform. I don’t know what specifically “everything works” means, but I assume you tested this app only using your own developer account? If you want it to be available for all users, then you will need to add the Android platform before you can submit for review.

Comment: @CBroe With “everything works” I mean that the FB SDK for login works fine in my Android App. Instead, what do you exactly mean with "all users"? And just to have a better idea on that, can you give a case when I might need to add a "Website" platform, for example. Thanks.

Comment: All users meaning the public - should anyone be able to download your app from the app store and use it, or is it just for yourself? // You would add the website platform, when you want to use the app on a website ...

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, I now understand that when I add an Android Platform i.e., it makes it possible for public to download App from App Store (the same would be for adding iOS as a Platform I guess). But, adding  a website, how can a public use an Android App from whatever website? Do you mean to be able to download the App?

Comment: I think the platform is been asked by facebook because it helps facebook to genuinely authenticate the API request from the mobile/ from any other sources. Incase of any discrepancies, the API request may be turned down.

Comment: _“But, adding a website, how can a public use an Android App from whatever website?”_ – this would not be for the Android app in that case, but a website app - features like login with Facebook, etc., directly integrated into your website.

Comment: Thank you guys. Now I'm a bit more illuminated ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments above indicate, this is pretty much the answer (fell free to correct me):

If your application is running in different platforms, this means that you should be able to login in the **same** account from different platforms, then that's where the "Add Platform" comes in play.

In my case, I had an Android App where users can sign up using their FB account.

If in the future, I want to create a website application, then obviously, the users should be able to access that application with the same FB account.

In this case, I add an Website as a Platform.